# Is there a way to get a notification when someone specific comes Online on Skype

Tags: skype

Is there a way to get a notification when someone specific comes Online on Skype?
I dont want a notification for everyone. 
Just a specific person. 
Is there a way to do this? 
Is there some kind of script that can do this?